# Is it possible to modify the Google Docs/Sheets right-click context menu?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

It's well known on how to make a custom upper menu item (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus), but can you append a function to the context menu when right clicking a cell or item?

Comment: no, create a sidebar / Add-on for those types of functions

Answer (score 20):

No.  Can't do it.  There is no class or method to modify the right click context menu.