# How to customize the right click popup menu of a sheet's tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to customize the right click popup menu of the tab of a sheet at the bottom?  Specifically, I wish to add to that menu a new menu item, one of my macro names currently available at tools.macros.myMacroName.

If possible, how to accomplish this?  Thank you very much!

Comment: most likely not possible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to modify the Google Docs/Sheets right-click context menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932041/is-it-possible-to-modify-the-google-docs-sheets-right-click-context-menu)

Answer (score 4):

Not possible sorry. 
Your options are any of those features available in the Class Ui. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html. 
Your macro/script could be set to act on the active sheet.